# moment.js - format string with century

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to get a moment object which matches July 8th 2021 from this code:

```
moment('121 07 08', 'CYY MM DD')
```

I'm trying to use century since the value is coming from a legacy database and it seems like moment.js doesn't support it. This is not the only instance of it, so I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Century is not supported by moment, but it's easy to be converted to years, and easy to handle.

Comment: What is 121 supposed to represent?

Comment: 121 is almost certainly 2021 - 1900. It's a space saving technique used in legacy databases. 1210708 is 7 digits so using a packed decimal format this would take up (7+1)/2 = 4 bytes. Storing 20210708 would be (8+1)/2 = 5 bytes. A difference of 1 byte adds up when you have a large database and years ago memory was very expensive.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a century modifier in moment, but 2 digit years where the values are less than 68 are assumed to be in the year 2000, per the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#parsing-two-digit-years):

> Parsing two digit years
>
> By default, two digit years above 68 are assumed to be in the 1900's
>   and years 68 or below are assumed to be in the 2000's. This can be
>   changed by replacing the moment.parseTwoDigitYear method.

C is ignored so it will see the 12 as the 2-digit year. Remove the C and the 1 and you're set.

```js
console.log(moment('21 07 08', 'YY MM DD').format('MMMM Do YYYY'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```